# Vars in static classes

Tags: php

I have a var in my class

```
protected $test = 'test';
```

Normally I would access this inside the class like:

```
$this->test;
```

But this gives me an error.

How can I access vars inside a static class?

Comment: Actually, it does work http://ideone.com/faPqcF. How are you accessing it, via other classes, or so ?

Comment: Your class only has static methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare the variable as `static` first.

```
static $test = 'test';
```

After that you can access it with `self::$test`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//declare
protected $test = 'test';
public $publicTest = 'test';


//access this inside the class
self::$test;


//access this inside the class on dynamic instance
static::$publicTest;
```